# Warning: Prop `className` did not match. when using styled components with semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styled-components, semantic-ui-react, next.js

I use this code to margin my Button from top:

```
const makeTopMargin = (elem) => {
    return styled(elem)`
        && {
            margin-top: 1em !important;
        }
    `;
}

const MarginButton = makeTopMargin(Button);
```

and whenever i use `MarginButton` node, I get this error: `Warning: Prop`className`did not match. Server: "ui icon left labeled button sc-bwzfXH MjXOI" Client: "ui icon left labeled button sc-bdVaJa fKCkqX"`

You can see this produced [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xvmq9jjzzq).

What should I do?

Comment: The link you shared is to port :3000 on an IP address. Unless you have made that IP address available to public traffic and have a currently running web server there, nobody will be able to access what you are running.

Try creating a minimal example of your problem using a tool like codesandbox instead. https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Sorry, that ip is actually a vps but it is not running right now for a reason. I will try to reproduce it now.

Comment: @brianespinosa Please see https://codesandbox.io/s/xvmq9jjzzq

Comment: I am looking at your console and there is no proptype warning for className.

Comment: I think it happens only in development environment. I can't reproduce it online.

Comment: I have this error happening two pages, none of the answers helped, did you end resolving this ?

Comment: You only need to add this line of code into your next.config.js file `module.exports = {
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  }
}`

Answer (score 120):

Or you could just add this to your `next.config.js`. This also makes it so next-swc ([speedy web compiler](https://github.com/swc-project/swc)) works to reduce build times. See [more here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30174).

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  compiler: {
    // Enables the styled-components SWC transform
    styledComponents: true
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me. All I had to do afterwards was restart my local server. Based on my limited understanding, it seems that this experimental value prevents mismatched classes created by styled-components as it is processed by the server and then the client.

Comment: As of Feb 2022 it appears that this no longer "experimental".  As @Abhilash Rathod points out in his answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71100071/718325), it now works under the `compiler` key instead of `experimental`.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect this (correct) comment.

Comment: I'm using Next/SWC, and this fix did not fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 78):

This warning was fixed for me by adding an .babelrc file in the project main folder, with the following content:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}
```

See following link for an example:
https://github.com/nblthree/nextjs-with-material-ui-and-styled-components/blob/master/.babelrc

Comment: This worked for me after I `npm i babel-preset-next`

Comment: So this works for me, but what's the explanation for this ?

Comment: After install `npm i babel-preset-next` I couldn't start my project :(

Comment: i used babel-plugin-styled-components package and RESTART project. it works

Comment: Next no longer uses Babel; what's the new version of this answer?

Comment: didn't work for me - `"next": "^13.4.2"`

Answer (score 34):

You should install the babel plugin for styled-components and enable the plugin in your .babelrc

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-styled-components"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 32):

The main reason I am posting this answer to help people understand the tradeoff. When we're using `.babelrc` in next project it's going to opt of SWC compiler which is based on Rust ([Learn More](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#why-swc)).

It's going to show message something like this when you opt for custom bable config.

```
info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc"
```

I did more digging on this to only find out following! [Ref](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled)

> Next.js now uses Rust-based compiler SWC to compile
> JavaScript/TypeScript. This new compiler is up to 17x faster than
> Babel when compiling individual files and up to 5x faster Fast
> Refresh.

So tradeoff was really huge, we can lose significant amout of performance. So I found a better solution which can solve this issue and keep SWC as default compiler.

You can add this experimental flag in your `next.config.js` to prevent this issue. [Ref](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#styled-components)

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  compiler: {
    // ssr and displayName are configured by default
    styledComponents: true,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**For Old versions form Nextjs < 12**, Go to `next.config.js` file and add this line inside `nextConfig` object:

```
  experimental: {
   // Enables the styled-components SWC transform
   styledComponents: true
  }
```

**for new NextJs above 12**:

```
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true
  }
```

if that does not work you need to make an NO SSR component wrapper like this:

```
// /components/NoSsr.js

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const NoSsr = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(NoSsr), { ssr: false })
```

Then you need to add warp No SSR with your component like this:

```
// /pages/index.js

import NoSsr from '../components/NoSsr'
import CircleButton from '../components/buttons/CircleButton'

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>Home Page Title</p>
      <NoSsr>
       {/* Here your styled-component */}
        <makeTopMargin ele={...} />
      </NoSsr>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try this, it works. The no ssr approach solves things.

Answer (score 6):

If you have already added babel plugins, delete the .next build folder & restart the server again

credit: Parth909 https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7322#issuecomment-912415294

Answer (score 5):

I was having the exact same issue and it was resolved by doing:

```sh
npm i babel-preset-next
npm install --save -D babel-plugin-styled-components
```

and adding this to .babelrc file:

```json
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Styled components server side rendering](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#server-side-rendering)

> Server Side Rendering styled-components supports concurrent server
>   side rendering, with stylesheet rehydration. The basic idea is that
>   everytime you render your app on the server, you can create a
>   ServerStyleSheet and add a provider to your React tree, that accepts
>   styles via a context API.
>
> This doesn't interfere with global styles, such as keyframes or
>   createGlobalStyle and allows you to use styled-components with React
>   DOM's various SSR APIs.

```js
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
try {
  const html = renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(<YourApp />))
  const styleTags = sheet.getStyleTags() // or sheet.getStyleElement();
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
  console.error(error)
} finally {
  sheet.seal()
}
```

```js
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { ServerStyleSheet, StyleSheetManager } from 'styled-components'

const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
try {
  const html = renderToString(
    <StyleSheetManager sheet={sheet.instance}>
      <YourApp />
    </StyleSheetManager>
  )
  const styleTags = sheet.getStyleTags() // or sheet.getStyleElement();
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
  console.error(error)
} finally {
  sheet.seal()
}
```

In my case as im using nextjs

```js
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({ renderPage }) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const page = renderPage(App => props =>
      sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />)
    );
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleElement();
    return { ...page, styleTags };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>{this.props.styleTags}</Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to add styled-components to my Next.js project. It still doesn't work. My issue is that when I reload the page deployed by npm run dev, it throws the error of server not matching the styles at the client end. I have even used the babel-plugin-styled-component plugin. Nothing seems to be working. Can you suggest something? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this issue following these steps.

1. Create a file named `.babelrc` in the root directory and configure the `.babelrc` file.
2. delete the .next build folder(It stores some caches).
3. Restart the server.
4. Hot reload the browser.

`.babelrc` configuration file

```
{
    "presets": [
        "next/babel"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "styled-components",
            {
                "ssr": true,
                "displayName": true,
                "preprocess": false
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

PropType errors are runtime errors that will let you know that the data expected being passed to a prop is not what is expected. It looks like the className prop that is being set on your component is not the same when the component is rendered on the server and when it is then rendered in the client's DOM.

Since it looks like you are using server side rendering, you need to make sure that your class names are deterministic. That error is showing you the class that is being created by your `styled-components` library on the server and how it is different from the DOM. For libraries that do not normally have deterministic class names, you need to look at advanced configurations. [Take a look at the styled-components documentation regarding specificity as it pertains to SSR](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#issues-with-specificity).

Comment: Is there a captureable event associated with the component/element comparison that triggers this warning? In my case, the warning is triggered when my own JavaScript adds classes to DOM elements before React finishes updating components in the DOM on first load. If I knew the event associated with the comparison activity and could listen for it, I could defer my own DOM manipulations until React is finished.

Answer (score 2):

```js
//1.  I got an error when using material-ui with Next.js 


/********************************************* */

//2.  The code I imported was like this  : 


const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {     //  root must change 
        width: 100 ,
    }
});

const Footer = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root} > { /*  root must change */}
            <p> footer copyright @2021 </p>
        </div>
    )

}
export default Footer;


/********************************************* */

//3. I changed the code like this :


const useStyles = makeStyles({
    footer: {   //  changed here to footer
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "blue !important"
    }
});

const Footer = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.footer} > { /*  changed here to footer */}
            <p> footer copyright @2021 </p>
        </div>
    )

}
export default Footer;



// I hope it works
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using *NextJS 12* and encountered the same issue, well error in the console, code was working ok.
I fixed it by creating a `.babelrc` file at the root of the project and add:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "next/babel"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "styled-components",
            {
                "ssr": true,
                "displayName": true,
                "preprocess": false
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Styled Components have full, core, non-experimental support in Next now (2022), but you have to turn them on:

Add the following to your next.config.js:

```
compiler: {
  styledComponents: true,
},
```

My full, mostly vanilla, next.config.js now looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  compiler: {
    // Enables the styled-components SWC transform
    styledComponents: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-1#improved-swc-support

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for those who are using **NextJs** version  > `v12.0.1` and **SWC** compiler. You don't have to add `_document.js` file nor do babel related stuff anymore since it has been replaced by **SWC** compiler since `v12.0.0`. Only that your `next.config.js` file should look like the following since **NextJs** supports styled components after `v12.1.0` and restart the server and it should work: [more here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#styled-components)

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  // add the following snippet
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed all the other advice, around setting up `.babelrc` (or `.babelrc.js`), but noticed this message [in the Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error#possible-ways-to-fix-it):

> When css-in-js libraries are not set up for pre-rendering (SSR/SSG) it will often lead to a hydration mismatch. In general this means the application has to follow the Next.js example for the library. For example if pages/_document is missing and the Babel plugin is not added.

[That linked to this file](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components-babel/pages/_document.tsx), showing that I needed to add this to `pages/_document.tsx` to:

```
// if you're using TypeScript use this snippet:

import React from "react";

import Document, {DocumentContext, DocumentInitialProps} from "next/document";
import {ServerStyleSheet} from "styled-components";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(
    ctx: DocumentContext,
  ): Promise<DocumentInitialProps> {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
}
```

[A blog post by Raúl Sánchez](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/deprecated-main/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js) also mentions this solution, [linking to the JavaScript version](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/deprecated-main/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js) if you're not using TS (`pages/_document.js`):

```
// if you're *not* using TypeScript use this snippet:

import Document from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        })

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      }
    } finally {
      sheet.seal()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using create-react-app, you can use thi solution.

File called styled.ts

```js
import styled from 'styled-components/macro';
import { css } from 'styled-components';

export const ListRow = styled.div`
  ...
  ...
`
```

Based on the files name, the prefix will be as following.

```js
`${file_name}__{styled_component_name} ${unique_id}`
```

Meaning when implemented it will have the following classname
[image]

Although it would be nice to specify from where the first prefix would be taken from, meaning instead of file_name, we take folder_name. I currently dont know the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on C. Molindijk's answer, this error occurs when server-side class is different from client-side because styled-components generates its own unique class Id's. If your Next app is server-side rendered, then his answer is probably correct. However, Next.Js is by default statically generated, so unless you enabled SSR, configure it like this without ssr set to true:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components"]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when using MUI, and i solved it,
instead of import like this `import { TableCell } from '@mui/material';`, change to `import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';` .the warning Prop className did not match will be disapeared. worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If the error for adding the class name "scroll-smooth" in the `<html>` tag or `<body>` tag then the error is fixed by adding `suppressHydrationWarning={true}`

You can also check this: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

```
<HTML
    lang="en"
    className="!scroll-smooth"
    suppressHydrationWarning={true}
>
```

or

```
<body
    suppressHydrationWarning={true}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

Replace:

```
import { styled } from "styled-components";
```

With:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
```

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46605#issuecomment-1639900755