# problem in withStyle defined in Material UI because of difference className in server and client

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, frontend, server-side-rendering

I'm using nextjs and Sass. All of my styles are worked fine but just when I'm using withStyles this warning appears

[image]

```js
const LikeButton = withStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: "#666666",
    fontSize: "1.3125rem!important",
    fontWeight: 700,
    maxWidth: "51px!important",
    width: "51px!important",
    minWidth: "51px!important",

    backgroundColor: "#fcfbfa",
    marginLeft: "1rem",
    border: "1px solid #dcdcdc",
    "& svg": {
      fill: "currentColor",
      color: "currentColor",
    },
    "&:hover": {
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      backgroundColor: "#fcfbfa",
    },
    "&.Mui-disabled": {
      backgroundColor: "#e6e6e6",
      color: "#666666!important",
    },
  },
}))(Button);
```

I did all solutions mentioned in this link
https://www.mashen.zone/thread-3621719.htm
but didn't solve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Prop \`className\` did not match. when using styled components with semantic-ui-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791163/warning-prop-classname-did-not-match-when-using-styled-components-with-seman)

Comment: @Giovanni Esposito I'm not using the styled component. I'm using material UI. All styles worked fine just when I'm using withStyles, this warning appear

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [MaterialUI makeStyles undoes custom css upon refresh in NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66089290/materialui-makestyles-undoes-custom-css-upon-refresh-in-nextjs/66089559#66089559)?

Comment: @juliomalves I did this config before