# Next.js 13 + Styled Components "Warning: Prop className did not match." error - how to migrate from babel to SWC?

Tags: next.js, styled-components, swc, next.js13

When upgrading the Next version from 12 to 13 I got the error "Warning: Prop `className` did not match." pointing to styled-components. My initial setup was with babel, including `babel-plugin-styled-components`, but when I stumbled across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791163/warning-prop-classname-did-not-match-when-using-styled-components-with-seman) I decided to try out SWC. My understanding was that it should solve my error, by following these steps. I have:
- Removed the file .babelrc to let SWC be the default compiler
- Added  to the next.config.js file

```
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true
  }
```

I also tried removing the `babel-plugin-styled-components` dependency and installed `swc-loader`, but I don't think that made any difference. How can I make sure that SWC is running (I guess it is), and how can I resolve the error (preferably by using SWC instead of Babel)?

Comment: Any luck? Having the same issue. Had to disable SWC and use .babelrc with             "styled-components",
            {
                "ssr": true,
                "displayName": true,
                "preprocess": false
            }. Would prefer using the default SWC instead of what seem to be a hackish solution